# executing Scroll and click event in facebook using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, facebook

driver.get(f'https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/{tag_keyword}/')

```
    link_total_box = []
    scroll_cnt = 0

  
    while True:
        source = driver.page_source 
        html = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser') 
        post_div = html.find_all('div', attr={'role': 'article'})
        scroll_down = 0
        for i in range(1, 11):
            elm_body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            print(f'Scrolling... {i}')
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5))
            scroll_down = i
        
        curr_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
        scroll_cnt += scroll_down
        print(f'scroll_cnt: {scroll_cnt}, current_height: {curr_height}')

        if curr_height == prev_height:
            print('\last_height: ' + str(prev_height) + '\n')
            break
        else:
            prev_height = curr_height
        
        if scroll_cnt >= 20:
            break

    try:
        post_div.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="mount_0_0_EK"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]""").click() # share_button
        time.sleep(2)

       post_div.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="mount_0_0_aC"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/span/span""").click() # copylink_button
        time.sleep(2)
        

    except:
        pass

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        '게시글 링크': pyperclip.paste()
    })

    link_total_box.append(df)
    link_df = pd.concat(link_total_box)
    link_df.to_excel(f'{desktop_path}\\태그_{tag_keyword}_게시글 링크.xlsx', index=False)
```

I want to execute 1)scroll 2) click 'share' and 'copy link' button 3) save links in an excel file

It's likely entering the hashtag page works fine but the problem is scrolling and clicking. I kept trying to search codes and fix but most of them didn't work out.

I'll be highly appreciated if you give just some tips on how to fix codes, or clarify the problem that makes this code do not work.

cheers

Comment: you do know that this is not allowed on facebook and you might get banned, right?

Comment: Also be aware that the classnames and html tags you look for may change at any moment. So even if you get it to work it will probably stop working very very soon.